# Two TCP clients as a single one?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Maybe this sounds stupid, but I need to connect a Java socket, for instance, to an already open stream of another application (the application "talks" to the server using a socket). I have found no information on how to do this at all. So, my question is: is that possible at all (hooking into an existing connection)?

P. S. I know that it is possible to read packets this way, but my aim is to have the ability to write as though from the other application.

Comment: Not really, no. You could create a proxy server in between though.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the quick response. A proxy server is of what I thought, too. Just wondered if there was a quite easier way to do that.

Comment: For obvious security reasons there's no general "hijack this TCP connection" functionality. You need root access for the privileges, and native code to actually connect to the TCP/IP stack. Technically it is doable, but from a practical point of view it's not.

Comment: Not with pure Java, unless you want to write native code that employs your operating-specific file-descriptor passing mechanisms. And that would require cooperation from the other application.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "root" on the machine, you can do whatever you want but it's not supported and definitely not easy.  You'd have to code into the kernel some kind of interceptor...  but this is easier done as a user-space proxy (see below).

Remotely, what you're asking to do would involve [IP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) in order to effectively "fake" the behavior of the session.  This is impractical for an existing session as the intruder wouldn't know enough details (chosen SYN numbers, etc.) to make it work.  Continued communication from the original server would also mess everything up.

It is possible as a "[man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)" if the intruder sits on a machine in the communication path so long as there are no protections in place such as TLS/SSL.

The only practical general solution is to place a special "[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)" server in front of the real server.  This would accept and forward all data from the main channel but also allow a separate side connection and would internally [multiplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing) the data to create a single stream to the real server.  The proxy server can be on the same machine as the real server and talk to the real server over the "localhost" interface (so as to not expose the real server to the network).

Answer (score 0):

Unix/Lixux processes can share file descriptor of a socket with an another processes.
Usually this is done by using set of system commands, like: `fork()`, `dup2()` and `execve()`.

For example widely used `inetd` superserver 'dups' TCP streams to `stdin` and `stdout` of the new process. So, a java program could use `System.in` and `System.out` to receive/send TCP payload.

More sophisticated support for `inetd` was added to java according to [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4673940) by adding method: `System.inheritedChannel()`.

But there are several drawbacks that may prevent you to use this approach:

- All operating systems won't support that.
- You must implement support into the original client or server. And that could be hard.
- Java program may not set socket options for controlling the connection.